# Solr - not returning me the complete rows

Tags: solr

myself new to Solr.

I have the below 2 issues :-

1. I am using Tomcat 6 and Oracle 10g as database. Solr 4 . When I deploy solr.war in tomcat I get exception in tomcat console that, dataimporthanler class not found. I have specified solr home and a lib directory in my solr home that contains all jar.
   Still why does solr war expects to put the jars in the solr.war lib folder?
2. I have indexed the entity with full import.
   I have a simple database table in Oracle. typical emp_id, emp_name, emp_dept.
   I have defined data-config.xml and currently have only one document and entity. I have updated schema.xml accordingly.
   when I do a /select query. I get only emp_id in the xml/json output.
   How do I say what fields I want in the response?
3. I have 2222222 rows in the database, I get only 10 rows and if I edit config xml then only I get specified rows. My database table can grow, how do I get complete rows?
   The problem is, I cannot say no of rows required which does not make sense since rows keep on increasing as transactions happen.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1.Check that if **lib** directory in Solr Home contains `apache-solr-dataimporthandler-x.y.z.jar` and `apache-solr-dataimporthandler-extras-x.y.z.jar` files. Also check the `solrconfig.xml` file whether lib directory is configured correctly or not.

2.Add [stored=true](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Data_Types) to the field definitions in the `schema.xml` file. If you don't set **stored=true** then your fields would not be shown in the output. If you want to return some fields then you can use [fl=fieldName](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) query options.

3.When you set **rows** parameter it will return that much results but you can also find a **numFound** field in the result that shows total number of rows found with given query.

Comment: Problem 2 is resolved. we need to specify required = true not stored=true.